# Substitute even or odd string matches

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal, pipe

Straight off the bat: this is not just about matching numbers.

There are lots of `**` scattered around **in a document**, and I need to replace them with `1` and `2`.

## Sample input

```
**Lorem ipsum dolor **sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ** 
Ad velit delectus ** quidem itaque eum **accusamus reprehenderit**
illo culpa **** praesentium** ea fugit ****hic in vel officiis, 
expedita sit **** et harum enim quaerat, **** ab corporis quo 
atque perspiciatis. Minima odit obcaecati** ** reiciendis, sed 
rerum ** labore. In fuga, ** aspernatur earum aliquid ** ****** 
**commodi delectus?
```

## Desired output

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor 2sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 1 
Ad velit delectus 2 quidem itaque eum 1accusamus reprehenderit2
illo culpa 12 praesentium1 ea fugit 21hic in vel officiis, 
expedita sit 21 et harum enim quaerat, 21 ab corporis quo 
atque perspiciatis. Minima odit obcaecati2 1 reiciendis, sed 
rerum 2 labore. In fuga, 1 aspernatur earum aliquid 2 121 
2commodi delectus?
```

The only thing I got in mind is doing a loop where replaces the first occurrence found (`s/\*{2}/1/`), then for the second (`s/\*{2}/2/`), rinse and repeat, but since I still don't know how to translate this into shellscript, I was wondering if this is doable with a couple of piping `sed` commands.

Comment: `echo "** ** ** ** ** ** **" | sed -E 's/\*\* \*\*/1 2/g; s/\*\*/1/'`

Comment: Sure the example is vague, but you're missing the point. I already mentioned that I have a **document** with lots of couple of asterisks `**` scattered around. I need to replace those.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Use `cat file | perl -0pe 's/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/1${1}2/gs' | sed 's/\*\*/1/'`

Comment: @Fabián - make it less vague, then.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Cyrus added a better sample input and desired output

Comment: Thank you for the more realistic example.

Comment: In your example you have `1` after `1`, ie. `1 ea fugit 1`. This was not intended?

Comment: @KamilCuk Unintended indeed, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
**Lorem ipsum dolor **sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ** 
Ad velit delectus ** quidem itaque eum **accusamus reprehenderit**
illo culpa **** praesentium** ea fugit ****hic in vel officiis, 
expedita sit **** et harum enim quaerat, **** ab corporis quo 
atque perspiciatis. Minima odit obcaecati** ** reiciendis, sed 
rerum ** labore. In fuga, ** aspernatur earum aliquid ** ****** 
**commodi delectus?
```

Your best bet is `perl` or `awk`:

```
$ perl -lpE 's/\*\*/$cnt++%2+1/ge' file
```

This uses perl's ability to eval an expression with the substitution.

Method:

1. Increment a counter `$cnt++` to get get `(0,1,2,3,...)` with each substitution in `s/\*\*/$cnt++%2+1/ge`;
2. Take the modulo `%2` of that series to get `(0,1,0,1,0...)` then add `1` to get `(1,2,1,2...)` for each alternating substitution.

By the same method, you can use `awk` with a `while` loop:

```
$ awk '{while (sub(/\*\*/,cnt++%2+1))}1' file
```

Alternatively, you can *slurp* the entire file (with `-0777`) and then do a global replace for `**[stuff between maybe on multiline]**` and replace with `1[stuff between maybe on multiline]2`:

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE '$s=$_; $s=~s/\*\*([\s\S]*?)\*\*/1${1}2/g; 
                   END{$s=~s/\*\*/1/; say $s;}' file
```

Note the final `$s=~s/\*\*/1/;` in case there are an odd total number of replacements.

All three cases, prints:

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor 2sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 1 
Ad velit delectus 2 quidem itaque eum 1accusamus reprehenderit2
illo culpa 12 praesentium1 ea fugit 21hic in vel officiis, 
expedita sit 21 et harum enim quaerat, 21 ab corporis quo 
atque perspiciatis. Minima odit obcaecati2 1 reiciendis, sed 
rerum 2 labore. In fuga, 1 aspernatur earum aliquid 2 121 
2commodi delectus?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '\n' $'\x1' |
sed 's/\*\*/\x2/g' |
sed 's/\x2\([^\x2]*\)\x2/1\12/g; s/\x02/1/' |
tr $'\x1' '\n'
```

1. The first `tr` substitutes newline for an unreadable character equal to hex number `0x01`.
2. Then the first `sed` substitutes two `**` for hex `0x02`.
3. Then any pattern `0x02<anything>0x02` is substituted for  `1<anything>2`
4. The last unamtched `\x02` is substituted by `1`.
5. Then the `0x01` is replaced back by a newline.

Live version at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/GdxI3K).

The substitution `*` for `0x02` is because, we can't do something along `sed 's/**\(^**\)**/...`, ie. greedy match a string until multi-char pattern is found (or I don't know how to do it). So I just substitute two characters `**` by one unredable character and handle it. That way i can handle single `*` correctly, like `**Lor*em ip*sum**`.

If you have GNU sed with `-z` option, the substitution for the newline is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zE 's/(\*\*)([^*]*(\*[^*]+)*)\1/1\22/g' file
```

Slurp file into memory. Match `**...**` and replace front `**` by 1 and back `**` by 2 globally throughout the file.

Comment: You need to add a final substitution to get a final `**` if there are a odd total number.

Comment: @dawg it is unclear from the OP if an odd number of `*`'s should be included in the previous `1...2` or the start of the next/last in-between block. As is the solution caters  for the test data provided.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[*][*]' '{ORS=(RT ? (ORS%2+1) : "")}1' file
1Lorem ipsum dolor 2sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 1
Ad velit delectus 2 quidem itaque eum 1accusamus reprehenderit2
illo culpa 12 praesentium1 ea fugit 21hic in vel officiis,
expedita sit 21 et harum enim quaerat, 21 ab corporis quo
atque perspiciatis. Minima odit obcaecati2 1 reiciendis, sed
rerum 2 labore. In fuga, 1 aspernatur earum aliquid 2 121
2commodi delectus?
```